# Changed from btao to Buffer but recieving TypeError when pushing to Vercel

Tags: javascript, base64, next.js, vercel

So i have this application in Next js where i need to encode my image to base64. I first tried using btao and it worked fine until i tried pushing to vercel which gave an error that btao was undefined.
I looked up how to fix it and found that using

```
Buffer.from(
   icon,
   "binary"
).toString("base64")
```

should work but after pushing to vercel again it gave me the following error:

```
Unhandled error during request: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received null
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Any idea why `icon` would be `null`? How is `icon` being declared? Can you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the awnser.

So my svf was saved as a raw string in my state and when the page loaded it was being encoded using Buffer.

To solve my issue i encoded the svg string with Buffer at the moment of upload and kept the encoded string as state so i didn't have to encode it when a page loads in.

Comment: How about just show us the final code